# Need to accest variable in a setOnClickListener method

Tags: java, android

I want that variable r to be global and I want SharedPreferences to be able to load variable r (String s) on global level.

What I'm making is something like a artificial robot HUNGER variable. I click on button and it adds +1 hunger, but every second I want to give it -1 hunger with timestamp. Also timestamp serves as indicator how long has device been offline and it gives -xx proportionaly.

As of right now, I can only add +1 to R since its local variable in onClickListener, I can't give it if( time has pased){ r = r-1 } because r is localy declared. I dont know how to get it out.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView broj;
    private TextView tekst1;
    private TextView posljednjeVrijeme;
    String stringTStamp;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                /**
                 * Ponavlja radnju svakih 4 sekunde, učitava vrijeme systema
                 */
                        final Handler ha=new Handler();
                        ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                                stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stringTStamp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SharedPreferences preferences3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences3.edit();
                                editor.putString("posljednjeVrijeme", stringTStamp);
                                editor.apply();



                                ha.postDelayed(this, 4000);
                            }
                        }, 4000);
                /**
                 * **************************************************************
                 */



        broj = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.broj);
        posljednjeVrijeme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.posljednjeVrijeme);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final String name = preferences.getString("vrijednost je ", "");
        final String name2 = preferences.getString("posljednjeVrijeme", "");
        if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {

            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+name);
            posljednjeVrijeme.setText("Zadnje vrijeme "+name2);
        }
        Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();
        if(Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2)>10){
            Toast.makeText(this, "POZDRAV GAZDA DUGO SE NE VIDJEH, UGASIO SI ME PRIJE " + (Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2))+ " SEKUNDI" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else{

        }


        tekst1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
        final SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            tekst1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                int r = 0+Integer.parseInt(name);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    r = r+1;


                    broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);

                    String s= String.valueOf(r);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
                    editor.putString("vrijednost je ", s);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Then don't declare it locally?

Comment: Use Firebase Job Scheduler (more battery friendly) or Alarm Manager to -> start a service in an timed interval ->  retrieve and edit the sharedPreferences variable. Your r if it is just an int so is fine to store it as a preference.

Comment: If i declare it globaly, it needs be to final. I can't make it final since it changes value all the time.

Comment: @AndrewLam AlarmManager can't repeat itself as I've read a lot of comments on internet. Since api19 it seems repeating itself does not work quite well. I could look into JobScheduler.

Comment: :) Store it in the preference, no need to worry about local or global. Local to the sharedPreferences, update using the sharedPreference editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public class say `Hunger.java` and add a static variable `public static int r` to it. Then use a Handler or Looper to decrement r by timestamp in your Activity

**onCreate()** for incrementing by timestamp:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       while(<your timestamp condition>){
         Hunger.r = Hunger.r - 1;
       }
    }
});
```

Before exiting the app in `onDestroy()` you can save the value of `Hunger.r` in `SharedPreferences`.

**onDestroy()**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("myvar",Hunger.r);
editor.commit();
```

You can load last value of `r` from SharedPreferences when the app restarts. If you want to keep decrementing r even when the app is offline, you can do so in `AsyncTask` or declare a `Service`.

You can retrieve value of r from SharedPreferences in `onCreate()` and set the value of static variable Hunger.r 
**onCreate()** [Initialising static variable when app restarts]

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Hunger.r = pref.getInt("myvar");
```

Your textView.onClickListerner could be like this

```
    tekst1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Hunger.r = Hunger.r + 1;

                        broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);

                    }

  }
```

In your original code you are repeatedly writing to SharedPreferences every time your hunger variable is updated. Writing data this way affects performance unnecessarily.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And If i wanted to add Hunger.java into my textView.setOnClickListener, how would the method look like mate?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. setter getter methods helped me to make my variable r accesable everywhere. Now my code on button click(textView) gives +1 and every 10 seconds if application is offline gives it -10 on r variable integer.

I have found the solution. getter setter method helped me to declare my r variable and I'm able to control my variable within every function. Solution, even tho code looks ugly.

```
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView broj;
    private TextView tekst1;
    private TextView posljednjeVrijeme;
    String stringTStamp;
    private int r;

    public int getDefaultR(){
        return r;
    }

    public void setDefaultR(int r){
        this.r=r;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                /**
                 * Ponavlja radnju svakih 4 sekunde, učitava vrijeme systema
                 */
                        final Handler ha=new Handler();
                        ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                                stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stringTStamp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SharedPreferences preferences3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences3.edit();
                                editor.putString("posljednjeVrijeme", stringTStamp);
                                editor.apply();



                                ha.postDelayed(this, 4000);
                            }
                        }, 4000);
                /**
                 * **************************************************************
                 */



        broj = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.broj);
        posljednjeVrijeme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.posljednjeVrijeme);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final String name = preferences.getString("vrijednost je ", "");
        final String name2 = preferences.getString("posljednjeVrijeme", "");
        if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {

            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+name);
            posljednjeVrijeme.setText("Zadnje vrijeme "+name2);
        }



        Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();

        if(Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2)<10){
            r = 0+Integer.parseInt(name);
            setDefaultR(0+Integer.parseInt(name)-10);
            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);
            final SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String s= String.valueOf(getDefaultR());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
            editor.putString("vrijednost je ", s);
            editor.apply();
        }

        else if(Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2)>10){
            Toast.makeText(this, "POZDRAV GAZDA DUGO SE NE VIDJEH, UGASIO SI ME PRIJE " + (Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2))+ " SEKUNDI" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            r = 0+Integer.parseInt(name)-10;
            setDefaultR(0+Integer.parseInt(name)-10);
            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);
            final SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String s= String.valueOf(getDefaultR());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
            editor.putString("vrijednost je ", s);
            editor.apply();

        }else{}





        tekst1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
        final SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            tekst1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    r = r+1;


                    broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);

                    String s= String.valueOf(getDefaultR());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
                    editor.putString("vrijednost je ", s);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });

    }
}
```